# Azure Activity Log - Download file from Blog

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

In Visual Studio Server Explorer with the Azure SDK installed.

If you open a blob container, you get a list of files.

If you click one of the files a progress bar appears showing it is downloading.

I cannot find where this file has been download to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's downloaded to `%TEMP%\CloudStorage\`.  If you want to save it somewhere else, you can right-click the file and *Save As* instead of double-clicking it.

Comment: Thanks I finally found it searching my drive. At first I ordered Windows folder by Modified Date, but it didn't show up.  I opened images, and log files then went to ...File...Save... but the origin folder didn't show up.  Thanks